# Dual booting Arch Linux and Windows with nvme ssd with raid (or fake raid, unsure)

Tags: arch-linux, raid, cfdisk

I'm attempting to dual boot Arch Linux with Windows 10, but have run into some problems with partitioning. I was following the installation wiki and SavvyNik's tutorial for dual booting Arch Linux, but when I got to partitioning the drive (single), I used

```
cfdisk /dev/nvme0n1
```

and the following showed up. Sorry it's a little difficult to read.

[image: Device already contains a isw_raid_member signature: it will be removed by a write command.]

Transcript: Device already contains a isw_raid_member signature: it will be removed by a write command.

Again, this only has one drive, an ssd. And it's nvme, not sda.

Is it safe to continue partitioning? I'm not entirely sure what would be removed (as the message stated) or how that would affect my computer.

I hope that's not too vague of a question.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to install Arch alongside an existing Windows installation or just preparing the system for dualboot?

Comment: Installing alongside an existing Windows installation.

Comment: Many systems use Intel RST/RAID and need to be changed to AHCI to work with Linux. But you have to first install AHCI drivers into Windows for it to work. AHCI enable - May have to unlock bitlocker if used
https://superuser.com/questions/1280141/switch-raid-to-ahci-without-reinstalling-windows-10

Comment: This isn't actual raid right? So if I did continue what would happen? If it wouldn't work then ig I'll try switching